# Adding form fields dynamically on button click in css grid structure

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have CSS grid  structure where i have already some form fields in place and have given a add button 
and on clicking it a set of form fields needs to be added.

````html
<div class="network-sub-form2">
      <div class="desc-btn">
        <label class="label revert btn-label vertical-alignment">AZ 2<sup class="star">*</sup></label>
        <button class="addButton btn-add-container button-revert vertical-alignment">
          <p class="add-desc">Add</p>
          <div class="add-btn">+</div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <select class="select-input" id="type" name="Type">
        <option>AWS</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
      </select>
      <div class="vertical-alignment">
         <div class="network-line-style"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="desc-btn">
        <label class="label revert btn-label vertical-alignment">Subnet 1<sup class="star">*</sup></label>
        <button class="addButton btn-add-container button-revert vertical-alignment">
            <p class="add-desc">Add</p>
            <div class="add-btn">+</div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-input">  
      <div class="radio-group">  
        <label class="label"><input type="radio">Public</label>
        <label class="label odd-radio"><input type="radio">Private</label>
      </div>
      <label class="label revert btn-label vertical-alignment">CIDR<sup class="star">*</sup></label>
      <select class="select-input" id="type" name="Type">
        <option>AWS</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
      </select>    ```
````

[image: This is how the form layout looks like]

this is the Css i have use

```
.formfields-network{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15,1fr);
  grid-auto-rows:1fr;
}

.network-heading{
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row:2/3; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: left;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:600;
letter-spacing: 0;
color: #333333;
opacity: 1;
}

.line-center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column:3/14;
  grid-row:3/4;
}
.network-line{
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  height: 1px;
  background: #666;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
}

.group1{
  grid-row: 4/17;
  grid-column: 3/14;
  display: grid;  
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.input-button{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex{
  flex: 5;

}

.button-container{


  align-items: flex-end;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.add-button{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #F08520;
}

.circle{
  color: #F08520;
}

.flex-labels{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-label{
 flex: 1;
 align-self: flex-start
}

.right-label{
 flex: 1;
 align-self: flex-start;
}



.form-input-2{
  height: 45px;
 background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #AAAAAA;

}



.left-input{
  flex:1;
  align-self: flex-start;

}

.right-input{
  flex:1;
  align-self: flex-end;

}

.gap{
  width: 30px;
}

.line-center1{
  grid-row:18/19;
  grid-column:3/14;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.vpc1{
  grid-row: 19/20;
  grid-column: 3/6;
}

.group2{
  grid-column: 3/14;
  grid-row: 20/32;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr  ;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  background: #F7F7F7 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  grid-row-gap:5px;
}

.az1{
  grid-column:2/6;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}

.flex1{
  flex:4;
}

.az1-inputselect{
  grid-column: 2/6;
  grid-row: 3/4;
 height:33px;
}
.az1-line{
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 2/6;
  opacity:0.6 ;
}
.az1-subnet{
  grid-row: 5/6;
  grid-column: 2/6;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.subnet-input{
  grid-row:6/7;
  grid-column:2/6;
  height:33px;
}

.radio-button{
  grid-row:7/8;
  grid-column: 2/6;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}

.radio-label{
  letter-spacing: 0;
color: #333333;
opacity: 1;
font-size:14px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.cidr{
  grid-row:8/9;
  grid-column: 2/6;
}

.cidr-inputselect{
  grid-row:9/10;
  grid-column:2/6; 
}

.line2{
  grid-row: 33/34;
  grid-column: 3/14;
}

.vpc2{
  grid-row:34/35;
  grid-column: 3/6; 
}

.group3{
  grid-column: 3/14;
  grid-row: 35/47;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr  ;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  background: #F7F7F7 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  grid-row-gap:5px;
}



.end-gap{
  grid-row:50/52;
  grid-column:1/17; 
  height:45px;
}

.endbtn{
  grid-row:47/50;
  grid-column:11/14;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

actually the issue i am facing here is I have a form which is a css grid and i place all the fields in the respective  order and suppose lets say i have a add button on say field 5 and on clicking it it should add  a label and text input.
The way to solve this problem which i think of is by adding a empty div below the field and onclick event add some html dynamically into that div,but this leads to the css breakage. Any suggestions on how to make this right and in general how to use the css grid properly so that dynamic content can be added.

Comment: Hey, first of all, welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide your css?

Comment: Hi @jamana-tarun are you trying to add a new form purely from CSS (via visibility) or are you allowed to use javascript to inject additional HTML dynamically?

Comment: hi @zeachco this needs to be done using javascript